# Lecture note or article on probability

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, reference-request

I am undergraduate student, I am looking for a lecture notes and articles on probability, especially random variables and law of distrubtion ... Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 1):

[This notes](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Ealdous/134/gravner.pdf) is a good reference for undergraduate probability.

[This one](http://statweb.stanford.edu/%7Eadembo/stat-310b/lnotes.pdf) and [this one](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Eweb6720/MATH%206710%20notes.pdf) are for graduate probability.

Comment: thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more precisely what your background consists of, it's hard to give a valuable answer. If you're looking for a mostly computational introduction to probability theory, [these notes on Probability and Random Variables](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-440-probability-and-random-variables-spring-2014/lecture-notes/) from MIT opencourseware are good. Slightly more advanced but with still mostly computational exercises, [Joe Blitzstein of Harvard University has a good online textbook](https://projects.iq.harvard.edu/stat110/home).

For something a little more rigorous, suitable for a first year graduate course in probability with measure theory, consider [Probability and Measure by Patrick Billingsley](https://www.colorado.edu/amath/sites/default/files/attached-files/billingsley.pdf).

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: actually i will start continuous random variable and i was wondering if there's some books where i could work out problems